# How do I change a sql server password that has expired from C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

When you are using a SqlConnection to connect to a MS Sql Server, if the password has expired you will get a SqlException Number: 18487 or 18488.

How can you change the user's password in code during the connection attempt?

Answer (score 4):

Use the static [SqlConnection.ChangePassword()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb8k729z(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
string original_dsn = "server=mysql.server.com,1433;database=pubdb;User Id={0};Password={1};"
string dsn = String.Format(original_dsn, username, password);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( dsn );
try
{
     conn.Open();
}
catch(SqlException e)
{
    if (e.Number == 18487 || e.Number == 18488)
           SqlConnection.ChangePassword(dsn, newpassword);
           // Try login again here with new password
    else
           MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
finally 
{
    conn.Close(); 
}
```